# How to print a return of a get statement

Tags: java, constructor

I'm working with a program that works over temperature conversion, and already have the code, but now I have to make a program that tests the code. For the part I need help with, I started out with a constructor like so:

```
   public Temperature(double newDegrees, char newUnits)
{
    degrees = newDegrees;
    units = newUnits;
}
```

then I made a method to get the temperature from either celsius or fahrenheit like so:

```
public double getC()
{
    switch(units)
    {
    case 'F':
    case 'f':
        convertedDegrees = 5 * (degrees -32)/9;
        return Math.round(convertedDegrees*10)/10.0;
        
    case 'C':
    case 'c':
        return Math.round(degrees*10)/10.0;
        
    default:
        return Math.round(degrees*10)/10.0;
    }
}
```

Finally I wrote in the coding for the testing:

```
System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Test case 14: temperature/units constructor and");
   System.out.println("getC() method.");
   System.out.println();
   Temperature t14 = new Temperature(52, 'F');
   System.out.println("Results of getC() method:");
   System.out.println("Verify 11.1 degrees C.");
   System.out.println();
   t14.getC();
```

My problem is when I run this, the temperature doesn't show up, and when I put in an output for this code, it returns the original temperature (52 degress F). How can I get it to show the temperature I'm needing (11.1 degrees C)?  Also, please note that I'm just starting to work with constructors and objects, I will note if any solutions haven't been gone over in my class. Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: `t14.getC();` returns the value, but it doesn't print anything (why should it?). You should `System.out.println(t14.getC());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your returned value to the `System.out.println` .

```
System.out.println( temp.getC() ) ;
```

This is very basic Java 101 stuff. So you should do more study before posting here. Your class textbook certainly would show this. Study the free-of-cost Java Tutorials from Oracle. And search Stack Overflow somewhat randomly to read code examples.